# html5 session storage scope

Tags: html, session

I am storing some data in session using html5 session storage. but the problems is it retains that data only into current tab. when I open a new tab the data is no more accessible there. then how we can say that it is a session??? is it possible that data make accessible to the all tabs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Session storage is only acceptable within the window that stored the data. [read here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage#Overview)

I would suggest using local storage if you want data to persist through multiple windows/tabs.